# Prioritize the emails and journeys in SF Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to limit the amount of emails a subscriber will receive in a certain period from all the journeys in the MC system and most importantly-- to prioritize the emails and journeys.

for example: a certain subscriber goes through 2 different journeys at the same time, a "new customer" journey and a "loan" journey. The "new customer" journey includes sending 3 emails per week and in the "loan" journey the subscriber should receive 2 emails that week. The weekly limit I want to set for the subscriber is 3 emails and give top priority to the "new customer" journey. The desired result is that the subscriber will only receive the three emails of the "new customer" journey because they have used the entire quota set and this campaign is a top priority. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks to the answers!

Comment: Please don't repost exactly same question, after it was closed. You have so far not shown any evidence of doing your own research, even after being pointed to historical posts which might be helpful. The short answer to your question is however: no, there is no OOTB functionality allowing you to achieve your goal

Comment: @LukasLunow Thank you but I did not get a complete solution for my question last time (there was no reference regarding the prioritization of the journeys) so I understood from what you wrote to me that I would try to formulate it more clearly and I was not able to edit the question because it was closed as far as I understand.
Thanks anyway for the direction to check the number of emails sent to the subscriber :)